# How to clear session on browser close?

Tags: magento-1.8, session, cookie

I want to store a value in session and to remove it on browser close. How can I do this?

Comment: I found this tutorial and it is working fine but still finding a way to remove my session value on browser close.

http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2013/05/magento-set-get-and-unset-session-variable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the cookie lifetime via the admin section to "0". This should mean that the cookie will expire on browser close.

Comment: Will it effect on the front end cookies?

Comment: @Adnan yes it should do.